# How to iterate in an array and skip some?

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

For example, I have this array in my Java program:

```
String nums[] = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" ...}
```

I want to write for-loop that would loop through the array and take every 2nd and 3rd letter and store each of them in two consecutive indexs in the array, skipping 4th, take 5 and 6th letters and store each in two consecutive indexes in an array , skipping 7th and keeps on doing it for an unknown size of an array.

So the final array would be `nums2 = {"b", "c", "e", "f", "h", "i"...}`

Comment: Which language?

Comment: iterate normally. Just add an if inside the loop to see if the value is one to be skipped. Looks like you're skipping every 3rd later starting with the first. So `if (i % 3 != 0)` for 0-based.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  What have you tried?  Please posting a [mcve], as that show us what you have tried, and where you went wrong, allowing us to actually help you.

Comment: @twain249 Yes that's correct, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This runs and prints `out = b, c, e, f, h, i`

```
public class Skip {
    public static String[] transform(String[] in) {
        int shortenLength = (in.length / 3) + ((in.length % 3 > 0) ? 1 : 0);
        int newLength = in.length - shortenLength;
        String[] out = new String[newLength];
        int outIndex = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < in.length; i++) {
            if (i % 3 != 0) {
                out[outIndex++] = in[i];
            }
        }
        return out;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] nums = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i" };
        String[] out = transform(nums);
        System.out.println("out = " + String.join(", ", out));
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your time, this is great! Glad to see that I had something very similar to this and now I know how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

You could use an if statement within the for loop that will skip every third letter starting from the second item within the array.

```
int j=0;    //separate counter to add letters to nums2 array
for(int i=0; i<nums.length; i++) {    //starts from 1 to skip the 0 index letter
    if (i%3 != 0) {    //should include every letter except every third
        nums2[j] = nums[i];
        j++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Starting at `i=1`, the expression `(i-1)%3` will immediately evaluate to `0`.  You've skipped the first, second, fifth, eighth, etc., giving `"c", "d", "f", "g", "i", "j", ...` which was not what was requested.

Answer (score 1):

```
for(int num : nums){
    if(num % 3 == 1) Continue;
    System.out.print(num + " ");
}
```

Sample java code as above

Answer (score 1):

Please always share what have you tried so far. People will be more receptive to help you. Otherwise, the most you deserve is pseudo-code. Try something like:

```
    for (1 to length)
    {
        if( i % 3 != 0)
        add to new array
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 String[] array = {"a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h" ...} //Consider any datatype 
 for(int i =1; i<array.length;i++) {
 if(i%3 == 0) {
 }
 else {
 System.out.println(a[array]);
 }

}
```

This way it will skip 4th element, 7th element,10th element,13the element whose corresponding index values are multiples of 3 and we are skipping that index elements by if condition..

Answer (score 0):

For the most concise way, use Java 9 streams:

```
String[] nums2 = IntStream.range(0, nums.length)
    .filter(i -> i % 3 != 0)
    .mapToObj(i -> nums[i])
    .toArray(String[]::new);
```